# Transcendence Degree of Integral Domain over a Field

Tags: field-theory

This may be trivial, but I am confused on the following issues.

1)  If we have a finitely generated integral domain R over a field k, why is the transcendence degree of R over k (that is, the transcendence degree of its field of fractions over k) necessarily less than the number of generators of R as an algebra over k.

2) In what instances must the generators of R be algebraically independent?

Comment: For 1), note that if $R = k[a_1,\ldots,a_n]$, then $\operatorname{Frac} R = k(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, and so $\operatorname{Frac} R$ has transcendence degree $\leq n$ over $k$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $R = k[a_1,\ldots,a_n]$, where $n$ is the transcendence degree of $\operatorname{Frac} R = k(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, then the $a_i$ must be algebraically independent. If $n$ is greater than the transcendence degree, then there must be some algebraic relation between them.

Comment: But why could one not choose a set of more than n algebraically independent elements in Frac R (where n is the number of generators)? How does one say explicitly that choosing more than n elements in Frac R necessitates their being algebraically dependent?

Comment: Because the transcendence degree is the size of a maximal algebraically independent subset of Frac R, or equivalently, the maximal size of an algebraically independent subset. This is more or less the definition of transcendence degree.

Comment: Wow I must be tired, thanks!

Comment: Actually the phrasing of my previous question may have been confusing. What I am asking is why m=(number of generators of R) >(or =) n=transcendence degree of Frac R over k. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious, but I seem to be getting myself confused.

Comment: It still seems like my initial comment answers that question. If there is something unclear about it, feel free to ask.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. If the transcendence degree is defined as the the maximal size of an algebraically independent subset, how do we jump from Frac R = k(a1,...,an) to the maximal number of algebraically independent elements of Frac R over k is necessarily less than n.

Comment: Check out the first paragraph of the proof of Lemma 9.23.3 [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/030D).

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer to your first question:

The transcendence degree of a field extension $L/K$ is the size of any transcendence basis for $L/K$, i.e. the size of any set of elements of $L$ that is maximal with respect to the property of being algebraically independent over $K$. The fact that you can use any maximal set is a really useful thing for computing transcendence degrees, akin to the fact that the dimension of a vector space is the dimension of any basis.

In your case, suppose that $R=k[a_1,\dots,a_n]$ is an integral domain. Then we have that $L = \operatorname{Frac}(R) = k(a_1,\dots,a_n)$. If all of the $a_i$ are algebraic over $k$, then $L$ is integral over $k$ so $tr.deg(L/k) = 0 \leq n$. Otherwise one of the $a_i$ is transcendental over $k$, and we can say $i = 1$ wlog. Then either all of the $a_i$ for $i \geq 2$ are integral over $k(a_1)$, or there is some $i$ with $\{a_1,a_i\}$ algebraically independent over $k$, again we can say $i = 2$ wlog. We can repeat the process until we get $m \leq n$ with $\{a_1,\dots,a_m\}$ algebraically independent over $k$ and $a_i$ integral over $k(a_1,\dots,a_m)$ for all $i > k$. But this means that $L$ is integral over $k(a_1,\dots,a_m)$ (since it is a finitely generated extension by integral elements), and so for any element $l$ of $L$,$l$ is integral over $k(a_1,\dots,a_m)$ and so $\{a_1,\dots,a_m,l\}$ is not an algebraically independent set. This is the same as saying $\{a_1,\dots,a_m\}$ is a maximal algebraically independent subset, which implies that $tr.deg(L/k) = m \leq n$, as required.

In fact, what we have actually proved is the the stronger statement that some subset of the $\{a_i\}$ is a transcendence basis for $L/k$. From this we can prove stronger statements. Firstly we can prove the second part of your question and see that the generators are algebraically independent iff $tr.deg(L/k) = n$. We can also prove that if any $r$ of the $a_i$ are algebraically dependent, then $tr.deg(L/k) \leq r$.